# How can I restore an iPad to factory defaults?

Tags: ipad

I'm planning to sell / give my old iPad to a friend.  I've already saved everything that I want off of the old iPad.  How can I restore the old iPad to factory default settings so that my friend can start fresh?

It's a first-gen iPad, in case it matters.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In iPad Settings, go to General, then Transfer or Reset, then "Erase All Contents and Settings". The next thing you see ( after confirmation) is the welcome screen as if just out of the box.

Also: If shipping it you might want to power off by holding top and bottom buttons until you see the "slide to power off" slider. I recently sold my iPad 2, cleared it to factory settings as described and powered off. Happy new owner received it with charge, ready to configure.

*Late note:*
If FindMy is enabled, you must disable this first [meaning you *must* have access to its iCloud account] or the new owner will not be able to use it, it will still be locked to you.