# Erase iPad without iTunes

Tags: ipad, password

I have an iPad I would like to restore to factory settings. I have the passcode.

A friend showed me how you can do this by just pushing some buttons, but I don't remember how he did it. I don't want to use iTunes if possible.

How can I do this?

Comment: The linked duplicate still applies. I have changed to reflect the newer Settings names & a note to release from FindMy, in order to transfer ownership.

Comment: There is no set of button pushes to reset, only to put it in DFU mode, which then forces you to connect to a computer. If your friend thinks there is a way… get him to show you again.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think the person was wrong. They said hold power and home - but when it comes back up - it still showing the passcode - I do have the passcode- but I want a total reset - and if its prompting for the passcode - then it has not been reset

Comment: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45254/9058) applies in your case. Power/home just forces a reboot, it doesn't trigger a factory reset.

Comment: I think what they showed you was the force reboot.